# Is this multi line if statement too complex?

Tags: c#, if-statement

I am validating input on a form and attempting to prompt the user of improper input(s) based on the combination of controls used.

For example, I have 2 combo boxes and 3 text boxes.  The 2 combo boxes must always have a value other than the first (default) value, but one of three, or two of three, or all text boxes can be filled to make the form valid.

In one such scenario I have a 6 line if statement to try to make the test easily readable:

```
if ((!String.Equals(ComboBoxA.SelectedValue.ToString(), DEFAULT_COMBO_A_CHOICE.ToString())
    && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBoxA.Text)
    && !String.Equals(ComboBoxB.SelectedValue.ToString(), DEFAULT_COMBO_B_CHOICE.ToString()))        
    ||
    (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBoxB.Text)
    || !String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBoxC.Text)))
{
    //Do Some Validation
}
```

I have 2 questions:

1. Should this type of *if* statement be avoided at all cost?
2. Would it be better to enclose this test in another method? (This would be a good choice as this validation will happen in more than one scenario)

Thanks for your input(s)!

Comment: It beats condensing it into one line.

Comment: Probably off-topic: I usually prefer `TextBoxA.Text.Trim()` to ensure accidential entered blanks do not count.

Comment: @Uwe Keim, I do use those tests, your not off topic, just didn't include them here because I was trying to write the question quickly.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In such a case I find it helps to move some of the logic out of the if statement and into some more meaningfully named booleans. Eg.

```
bool comboBoxASelected = !String.Equals(ComboBoxA.SelectedValue.ToString(), DEFAULT_COMBO_A_CHOICE.ToString());
bool comboBSelected = !String.Equals(ComboBoxB.SelectedValue.ToString(), DEFAULT_COMBO_B_CHOICE.ToString());
bool textBoxAHasContent = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBoxA.Text);
bool textBoxBHasContent = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBoxB.Text);
bool textBoxCHasContent = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBoxC.Text);

bool primaryInformationEntered = comboBoxASelected && textBoxAHasContent && comboBSelected;
bool alternativeInformationEntered = textBoxBHasContent || textBoxCHasContent;

if (primaryInformationEntered || alternativeInformationEntered)
{
    //Do Some Validation
}
```

Obviously, name the combo and text boxes to reflect their actual content. When someone has to work their way through the logic several months down the line they'll thank you.

Comment: +1 and accepted, I agree that this will be the most maintainable way to proceed, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

- a) Doesn't have to necesarily be avoided at all costs. The code works. But it is certainly messy, confusing and I would say could be difficult to maintain.
- b) Yes. Give it a relevant name so that the code reader knows what is going on there.

Answer (score 2):

I personally wouldn't have a big issue with code like this. (Your last set of parentheses seem unnecessary.)

Generally, I'd like to keep my if statements simpler. But all your conditions are simple ones. If you really need to test that many tests, then I'd keep it like it is.

Answer (score 1):

It is not very readable yes. But you can shorten it:

```
!String.Equals(ComboBoxA.SelectedValue.ToString(), DEFAULT_COMBO_A_CHOICE.ToString()
```

could also be written as:

```
ComboBoxA.SelectedValue.ToString()!=DEFAULT_COMBO_A_CHOICE
```

I presume DEFAULT_COMBO_A_CHOICE is already of string to ToString si superflous.

also the parenthese around

```
(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBoxB.Text)
|| !String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBoxC.Text))
```

are not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

IMO such conditions should be avoided (though not at all costs). They are very difficult to read an maintain.

There are several ways of doing that

Try and group the conditions according to the behavior they represent. For example

```
if (OrderDetailsSelected() && ShippingAddressProvided() )  
{
```

This way you can also avoid the duplication of the conditions within your form.

Secondly, you can use the [Boolean Algebra](http://sandbox.mc.edu/~bennet/cs110/boolalg/simple.html) to simplify the expression and

Use [Extract Method](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html) refactoring to move conditions, which are difficult to read in functions to avoid duplication and make them more readable.

For ex. The condition

```
String.Equals(ComboBoxB.SelectedValue.ToString(), DEFAULT_COMBO_B_CHOICE.ToString())
```

can be extracted into a function

```
private bool IsDefaultA() { return ... }
```